# When does a node checkpoint itself

Tags: corda

I understand there's some annotation related to `@Suspendable` to mark a function as serialisable. How much does a flow checkpoint itself?

Does a node checkpoint itself only when there's a `send`/`sendAndReceive` when it waits for a response? Or does it serialise checkpoints at an interval?

Given a flow that does nothing but computation, how much does it serialise/write to disk, and does this affect performance if there's a peak load of read/write from other thread doing vault queries/writing.

How does `@Suspendable` play a part in the these private methods that just do computation and nothing else. If a method gets annotated, it will only get serialise on the next `send` else nothing gets serialised?

Example

```
@Suspendable
override fun call() {
        val states = querySomeStates()
        computeSomethingHeavy(states)
        decideSomething()
}

@Suspendable
private querySomeStates()

@Suspendable
computeSomethingHeavy()

@Suspendable
decideSomething()
```

Answer (score 3):

`@Suspendable` marks a function as *potentially* suspendable. The flow is *actually* suspended only when one of the following operations is performed:

- Flow start
- `send`
- `receive`
- `sendAndReceive`
- `waitForLedgerCommit`
- `getFlowInfo`
- `sleep`

When one of these operations is performed, the node uses Quasar to capture the execution stack and create a checkpoint. If a function does not perform any of these operations, no checkpoints will be created. This is true even if the flow is doing heavy computation and/or the function is marked `@Suspendable`. In other words, Quasar does *not* do preemption, meaning we don't "checkpoint periodically", but only at specific call sites.

For example, here is the sequence of checkpoints in a simple flow:

`@Suspendable
fun call() {
  // checkpoint!
  sendSomething()
  computeSomething()
}
@Suspendable
fun sendSomething() {
  send() // checkpoint!
}
@Suspendable
fun computeSomething() {
  heavyComputation() // no checkpoint!
}`